# Double-clicking issue after installing Windows update KB3013455

Tags: windows, windows-vista, updates, double-click

Let me start off by saying that I do not install anything on this workstation, except Windows updates (which I should probably stop doing as well after I fix this issue). The unrelated problem started after update KB3013455 was installed in Feb. 2015. To spare your time for explanation, it messed up Windows fonts. [Here's a recap.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_update/kb3013455-ms15-010-causes-font-corruption/8640d38d-19bd-46b6-9af0-6213c05107d3)

To be able to use my computer I had to uninstall it manually. After which I started to notice that once in a while when I left-click something, it gets interpreted as a double-click. Unfortunately, the issue doesn't manifest itself all the time.  I also know that it is system-wide because it happens in several programs.

After I rolled back KB3013455, I installed it back along with the [fix KB3037639](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3037639), hoping that it would solve my double-clicking woes, but it didn't...

So I was wondering what the solution was to this problem

My OS is Vista x64.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is really an issue. I started noticing it a couple of weeks ago. I have tried multiple things to solve it, but when I plug my wireless USB mouse into my personal laptop it works fine. I turned off power save on the USB ports, I turned off the trackpad. I unplugged and replugged the USB reciever and rebooted. I installed the proper driver for my mouse from Kensington and I changed the power saving settings and USB port the mouse is using. Oh, I also turned off power saving overall for USB. No joy yet.

I even had to click three times in this box to get the focus right so I could type. Sometimes it is one, sometimes two and often three clicks before anything will respond. Now I have to figure out how to uninstall update KB3013455 manually. Fortunately, I lived through the DOS, Win 3.1, OS/2 and early Linux days where much installing and configuring of drivers and hardware was done manually.

I just uninstalled KB3013455 and it seems better, but not completely resolved. Now I'm going to go in a uninstall the Windoze mouse driver and see if that helps. Then I'll start researching mouse focus issues. Oh, the uninstall of KB3013455 was easy in the Control Panel (and I hope it actually uninstalled that update, but I'll have to go and check). More later.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging this as an issue. I did uninstall KB3013455 as well and it did not fully resolve the issue. It's quite sporadic. After the research that I've done, it seems like the issue manifests itself on Windows Vista. Is that the OS that you're experiencing it on?

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch out your external mouse with another one (if you are using one)
2. Check for software / driver updates
3. Mess around with the double - click settings to see if that changes anything
4. If you have nothing special installed, reinstall the OS
5. Is the issue *really an issue*? As in, how badly is this affecting you and/or how much will you be using this computer?

Comment: :) Thanks. Obviously reinstalling OS would fix the issue. As for external mouse, I don't think I installed anything for it. I just plugged in its USB dongle and it started working...

Comment: Right so just unplug it and plug it back in and see how that goes. Good luck! :]